# Avoid newline in python output

Tags: python, csv, merge, compare

Code snippet below compares two csv files and merge them. My problem is that the second file is printed in new lines.

```
import csv
import dateutil.parser

with open('a.csv', 'r') as f1:
   feed = f1.readlines()

with open ('b.csv', 'r') as f2:
    for line in f2.readlines()[1:]:
      line = line.split(',')
      ts = dateutil.parser.parse(line[3])
      print(ts)
      for i, log in enumerate(feed):
        ls = log.split(',')
        ts_start = dateutil.parser.parse(ls[0])
        ts_end   = dateutil.parser.parse(ls[1])
        if (ts >= ts_start) and (ts < ts_end):
           print(ts, ts_start, ts_end)
           name, tags, mean = line[0], ','.join(line[1:3]),line[-1]
           feed[i] = ','.join([log, name, tags, mean])

with open('c.csv', 'w') as f:
 f.writelines(feed)
```

file a:

```
2015-11-04T13:35:18.657Z,2015-11-04T13:47:06.588Z,load,INSERT
2015-11-04T13:47:47.164Z,2015-11-04T14:07:13.230Z,run,READUPDATE
```

file b:

```
name,tags,time,mean
memory_value,"type=memory,instance=buffered",2015-11-04T13:35:00Z,
memory_value,"type=memory,instance=buffered",2015-11-04T13:45:00Z,1.32    
memory_value,"type=memory,instance=buffered",2015-11-04T14:05:00Z,1.11
```

Output:

```
A1,A2,A3,A4,
A5
B1,B2,B3,B4,
B5,
```

Expected output:

```
A1,A2,A3,A4,A5
B1,B2,B3,B4,B5
```

How can I acheive this?

Thanks

Comment: By "output", do you mean "contents of c.csv", or "what gets printed to stdout"?

Comment: Can you provide sample copies of a.csv and b.csv?

Comment: please provide the files as code blocks in the question, not as an external link.

Comment: You're importing the `csv` module, but not actually using it at all in your code. You may want to, as it can make sure you get the newlines right in the output. Note however that it does have some requirements for how you open the file (you need to open in binary mode in Python 2, or use `newline=""` in Python 3).

Comment: Some digression: never use `for line in file.readlines()`, use `for line in file` instead. Similarly, you can also write line-by-line inside the for loop (`f.write('%s\n' % feed)`). This way you will not load all the data into memory and will get rid of trailing `\n`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings in the list returned by `readlines` include the newline character at the end of each line, so these may inadvertently be included as you do string manipulation on that data. In particular, `','.join([log, name, tags, mean])` will have a newline between `log` and `name`, because `log` ultimately came from `f1.readlines()`.

Try stripping the newlines from each line before doing anything with it.

```
  for i, log in enumerate(feed):
    log = log.strip()
    ls = log.split(',')
```

It may also be necessary to do `line = line.strip().split(',')` at the top of the first for loop instead of just `line = line.split(',')`. The output looks OK on my machine without it, but I'm not 100% sure that it exactly matches your desired output.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Just one issue. Now both two lines are one. I mean the second line "2015-10-04-...." also continues after first line while should appear after first one in a new line.

Comment: What happens if you change the last line to ` f.write("\n".join(feed))`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of python you are using you may need to change the 'r' and 'w' to 'rb' and 'wb' in order to read and write files in binary mode. This should help with the new lines.